# Write your own function to create a uniform random distribution in C++

Tags: c++, random

I know there are a few libraries offering functions to generate random distributions. Well, I want to write my own function, which

1. creates a uniform distribution
2. creates an exponential distribution

To do so, I have created a Linear Congruential Generator:

```
long Module::LCG() 
{
    RN = (16807*RN)%(2^31-1);
    return RN;
}
```

And now, I don't know how to proceed. For a uniform distribution, I need to have both an interval in which the generated numbers lie, and a mean and a standard deviation:

```
long Module::createUniform(int min, int max)
{
    for(int i=min; i<=max ;i++)
    {
     LCG();    //can I invoke LCG() here ? 
    }
}
```

And I'm missing out on the mean and standard deviation here, but don't know as on how to include them. Also, both `createUniform` and `LCG()` are public functions of the class Module. Can the function `createUniform` even invoke `LCG()`? 
Oh ya, the initial seed of RN is 1000. I don't know if there's a better way to create the LCG than simply picking one initial value for RN?

Ok, apparently writing these functions on my own  isn't very smart. So I have made some changes:

```
long Module::LCG() 
{
    RN = (16807*RN)%(2 << 31 -  1); // '<<' corresponds to a left-shift of the binary number
    return RN;
}

long Module::createUniform(int min, int max)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(min,max); //part of 'random' - library
    int p[max-min] = {};
    for(int i=min; i<=max ;i++)
    {
     p[i] = distribution(LCG(),LCG());   // can I invoke LCG() by createUniform ?
    }
}
```

Would sth like this work?

Comment: `2^31` does not do what you think it does. Try printing the result.

Comment: Given min and max, then mean and stddev are redundant, no?

Comment: @Baum mit Augen: whops! okay, well I have changed this expression to `std::pow(2,31)` , thx!

Comment: @ Oliver Charlesworth: My statistics isn't the best. I know that the mean is simply 1/2 min+max. And the variance can also be calculated from min and max. But how do I make sure my LCG() only gives out random numbers that are uniformly distributed?

Comment: @Luk Better than `pow` would be `1 << 31` so you don't needlessly involve floating point numbers.

Comment: Descriptions and calculation details for most of the common distributions are available online from NIST (National Institute of Standards and Technology). Just use google.

Comment: First try to make a uniform real (not int, may be double) distribution in range `[0, 1)` then the rest should follow.

Comment: Once you are done playing, please just use `std::uniform_int_distribution` and `std::uniform_real_distribution`.

Comment: @ Jasper: ok, could you maybe have a look at my edit ?

Comment: @Luk: If you're willing to use the standard library, basically everything you want to write [already exists there](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random). A linear congruential engine
, two uniform distributions, an exponential distribution, etc.